# I have 2 arrays, how to merge them with the same length but different indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays in an array of object and both are having the same length, how to merge them and values should be replaces(array has null values).

> obj

```
obj=[ [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      "YES",
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],[
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      "YES",
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ]]
```

Here in the above code, array1 has value at 23rd index and array2 has value at 22nd index and rest of values in both the array are null, and both the arrays are having same length. So I need an array with having same length, and in 22nd and in 23rd indexes I need respective values and rest values should be null.
Output(result) array should look like the below array.

> result

```
result= [
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      "YES",
      "YES",
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null,
      null
    ]
```

Comment: you can do a simple `null` check and replace the values using a `for loop`

Comment: ccan u please demonstrate with the piece of code

Comment: What is the expected behavior when for an index i, both array1[i] and array[2] !== null?

Comment: `const result = obj[0].map((_, i) => obj[1][i] || obj[0][i])`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you take the value of the last occurrence child object to merge from.

```js
obj = [ [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "YES", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ], [ null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "YES", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, ], ];

const mergeObj = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  return acc.map((el, i) => cur[i] ?? el);
});

console.log(mergeObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.reduce` implementation.

**Logic**

- Assign the first node from `obj` array as the initial output.
- Loop through the `obj` array first, loop through individual array in `obj`, Assign the value of each node as the logiacl or of accumulator and node from `obj` array.

```js
const obj = [
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "YES", null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "YES", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
]
const result = obj.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  curr.forEach((node, index) => acc[index] = acc[index] || curr[index])
  return acc;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: A suggestion: If you want to use the first element to be the first `acc` in the `reduce()`, you can omit it, and you will take it as `acc` in default. Therefore, you don't need to set `obj[0]` as default `acc` for the `reduce()` in the first place.

Comment: @ikhvjs That was an info for me. Thanks!!.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const obj = [
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "YES", null, null, null, null, null, null, null],
  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, "YES", null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
];

let result = Array(obj[0].length).fill(null);
result = result.map((val,idx)=>{
  return obj.map(item => item[idx]).find(item => item != null) || val;
})

console.log(result);
```